# God made them male and female - is this truth now redundant?

Tags: sexuality, civil-government

Does the church have another opportunity to simply follow the world into a whole new level of absurdity, or is there any reason to draw a line in the sand on this matter of self-identification?

One example.

After getting laws passed recently that allow anyone to identify as whatever they like, we are seeing some kickback from women's sporting clubs, associations etc., who demand that the laws be changed to safeguard women's sport. It is completely pointless ( and devastating) to spend a lifetime training, only to be beaten (soundly thrashed) unfairly by 'male' competitors identifying as female. Let alone some safety matters that also *weigh* in to this issue.

We have clearly defined categories in sport where weight, age, experience, etc., are used to maintain fairness within competition. Apparently sex is no longer one of those categories.

Does the church have some responsibility to mankind and to God to make a stand here? Or is it all too little, too late?

Comment: One thing that occurs to me when reading this - there was someone, a famous guy, who really didn't seem concerned about offending people in positions of power. Who was it again? Oh, I forget. Ah well. We probably should just do whatever the secular culture tells us to do.

Comment: This looks more like an argument than a real question. Who is it directed towards? What kind of Christians are saying that it's too late to stand by God-given Biblical principles?

Comment: @curiousdannii Episcopalians

Comment: I don't think we've ever allowed "The Church" type questions on the site.  You know as well as anyone that we're without a concrete leader. Maybe ask, "What ecumenical hurdles would Churches have to go through to formally define man and woman as doctrine?"

Comment: Doctrine? We don’t need more doctrine, we need to hold the bible as the standard or the worlds new fanciful standards. Mostly, it seems, the church is the world’s, not God’s on such matters. God has already provided truth, we don’t need doctrine to validate it.

Answer (score 4):

The Christian body of believers do have the God-given responsibility to mankind to stand against this evil stand by the Kingdom of Hell to pollute the image of God.

In Genesis, God makes it clear that He made us and in making us He only defined to sexes (genders) as being male and female.

According to Biologists, you can have surgery to modify your body parts. But the one thing you cannot change is your sex. Men are characterised by the fact that they have Y-STR DNA and mtDNA. Women are characterised by only having mtDNA.

The devil is the author of confusion. All these different genders pushed on us by liberals is leading to stressful confusion in people. Especially children. Children today have so many pressures. They are being sexualised and even President Obama said he backs teaching Kindergarten children about sex, and children have been given homework that even requires them to talk to their dads about their erections and ejaculations.

In the USA, one Tulane professor called Melissa Harris-Perry has even stated that your children are not only your children, they belong to us all. And Klaus Schwab, Bill Gates, the IMF, the UN, the EU, and others are working together to bring about the Fourth Industrial Revolution and the Global Reset, in which "You will own nothing and be happy." The plan was put in place when Agenda 21 became official.

In 2 Thessalonians 2:3, we are informed as Christians that the Anti-Christ ruler cannot come to power and be revealed until there is a great falling away of believers.

> **2 Thessalonians 2:3** New International Version
>
> 3 Don’t let anyone deceive you in any way, for that day will not come until the rebellion occurs and the man of lawlessness[a] is revealed, the man doomed to destruction.

> **2 Thessalonians 2:3-4** Jubilee Bible 2000
>
> 3 ¶ Let no one deceive you by any means: for that day shall not come except there come a falling away first and that man of sin be revealed, the son of perdition, 4 opposing and exalting himself against all that is called God, or divinity, so that he as God sits in the temple of God, making himself appear to be God.

People will be sucked in by the evil ones causing a great many to fall away from the faith. This is the danger of progress denominations that do not stay true to the written word of God! And that is why you need the Holy Spirit gift of discernment to discern between good and evil, lies and truth.

If we do not make a stand and inform our fellow brothers and sisters, they will embrace the devils teachings and be led astray.

> **2 Timothy 4:3-4** Jubilee Bible 2000
>
> 3 For the time will come when they will not endure sound doctrine, but, having itching ears, they shall heap up unto themselves teachers who shall speak to them according to their own lusts, 4 and thus they shall turn away their ears from the truth and shall return unto fables.

And as for God's truth about malke and female now being made redundant, this is what God has to say about the word's He has spoken:

> **Matthew 24:35** Jubilee Bible 2000
>
> 35 The heaven and the earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away.

So, only those people who carry the spirit of rebellion against God's word would push that God made male and female only is now redundant. And so the true believer should stand against such evil nonsense whose only purpose is to destroy the human spirit.

The devil knows his time is running out, and he wants to take as many humans into the lake of fire to suffer with him just to spite the God he rebelled against.

We cannot afford as believers to be part of this continual rebellion, and we MUST AT ALL COSTS (EVEN OUR OWN LIVES) adhere to what God has taught us through His written word, and what He has commanded us to do.

There is only male and female as God created us. There is no other sex or gender.

Comment: 'In the USA, one government official has even stated that "Your children are not only your children, they belong to us all."' – I did a Google search for that quote and it appears that this is false. Can you please either provide a source for that quote or remove it from your answer?

Comment: MSNBC Host Melissa Harris-Perry - We Own YOUR Children!: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAAMGatMHss

Comment: Well, Melissa Harris-Perry isn't a government official and she didn't say the words "your children are not only your children, they belong to us all." So I suggest editing your answer to fix these inaccuracies.

Comment: Fixed. That's exactly what she is saying when you read between the eyes in connection to what is actually happening to children's education in the USA. Couple that with After School Satan clubs, and drag queens normalising their behaviour in schools by reading children's stories, and you can see the devil ensnaring children and polluting them. Many parents in the US are wise to what is going on, which is why they have chosen to home school.

Comment: Also removed the quotes but kept the text.